# Form of Spin Four-vector

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

The spin angular momentum of a gyro is represented, in special and general relativity, by a spin four-vector $S^{\mu}$. In the rest frame of the gyro, the spin four-vector takes the form $S^{\mu}=(0,S^{i})$, where $S^{i}$ is the ordinary three-vector angular momentum and the time component $S^{0}$ is zero. Why does the spin four-vector have vanishing time component in its rest frame? The four-velocity of a particle does not follow this pattern -- it has a non-zero time component in the rest frame of the particle. Is there a way to see why $S^{0}=0$?

Comment: E.g. the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_angular_momentum#Intrinsic_angular_momentum) details the definition and calculation of that vector, and it turns out to not have a time component in that frame. Can you be more specific what you want to know about that?

Comment: Where a lot of vectors generalize to 4 vectors, spin and angular momentum (and magnetic fields)  generalize to a 4x4 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

So in a four-dimensional orientable space we have a $[0\;4]$ orientation tensor $$\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} = - \epsilon_{\beta\alpha\gamma\delta} = - \epsilon_{\gamma\beta\alpha\delta} = - \epsilon_{\delta\beta\gamma\alpha}$$Usually with respect to some basis we choose $\epsilon_{0123} = 1$ or so to finish off the specification  of the whole tensor. Since we could just as easily get the same orientable space by choosing $\epsilon_{0123} = -1$ these are sometimes called "pseudovectors" and "pseudotensors", but you can flip that perspective around and just say "this space just *has* this orientation tensor by definition" and reflections will simply change the sign of the components of the orientation tensor, leading to a consistent calculation with no "pseudos" to speak of.

Now suppose you have a bunch of worldlines of interacting particles: due to Poincaré symmetry and Noether's theorem there are some conserved quantities $P^\mu$ and $J^{\mu\nu},$ and while [there is no perfect definition of "center of mass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass_(relativistic)), we are free to choose the frame where $P^\mu$ points purely in the time-direction as the "center of mass frame". Regardless [there is a 4-covector called the Pauli-Lubanski spin pseudovector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli%E2%80%93Lubanski_pseudovector) defined by the orientation tensor as:
$$ S_\alpha = \frac12~\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}~P^\beta~J^{\gamma\delta}$$
However in this frame in particular it has no time component, and it's for a super-simple reason.

Let $T^\alpha$ be the unit 4-vector in the time direction for this particular center-of-mass-frame. In this frame, $P^\mu = m c^2 T^\mu$ for some effective mass $m$. This means that the time component of the spin vector is therefore $$S_\alpha T^\alpha = \frac1{2mc^2}~\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}~P^\alpha ~P^\beta~J^{\gamma\delta}$$However, $A_{\gamma\delta} = \epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} V^\alpha V^\beta$ is $0_{\gamma\delta}$ for any $V^\alpha$ because of antisymmetry: the first equality in the first equation in this answer says that it must be equal to $-\epsilon_{\beta\alpha\gamma\delta} V^\alpha V^\beta$ which under the $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$ relabeling isomorphism is just $-A_{\gamma\delta};$ the only tensor which is its own negative is the zero tensor.

Therefore, the component of the spin 4-vector in the center-of-mass frame is 0.

Comment: $J^{\mu \nu}=x^{\mu} P^{\nu}-x^{\nu} P^{\mu}$. Why is $\epsilon_{\alpha \mu \nu \gamma}J^{\mu \nu} P^{\gamma}$ not zero. Since $J$ contains a four-momentum, therefore, the contraction between $J P$ and $\epsilon$ should be zero.